# Apache web server timeout after 60 seconds

Tags: php, apache, timeout, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am experiencing timeout after 60 seconds for apache web server + php running in IBM softlayer.

These are my settings (httpd server restart after these settings)

```
httpd.conf  
TimeOut 300
Timeout 300
```

* tried both at the same, also single entry of TimeOut and Timeout only.

```
php.ini
max_execution_time = 300
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(10000);  //Just to make sure
sleep(70);
echo "Successful";
?>
```

## Using Command Prompt

```
php test.php
```

Result is Successful

## Using different browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Safari)

```
http://mysite/test.php
```

Result :  Timeout exactly at 60 seconds!

## Logs

php_error.log and httpd error_log
No errors!

I've found similar articles about this, but everybody is pointing at max_execution_time and Timeout.  So far, no help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: TimeOut and not Timeout

Comment: Yes, typo - should be TimeOut.

Comment: tried both at the same, also single entry of TimeOut and Timeout only.  Still no luck

Comment: Had the same issue.
The problem on my side was a load balancer timeout. We're using AWS load balancer and it's default timeout was 60 seconds, this was a pain to catch, hope it could help others.

Comment: @Rony this is incredible. I have no idea how you caught that error, but same for us. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 4):

many limitation are exists in php and apache server too

**1. Apache limits:**

```
find httpd.conf in your apache server : 

 c:\WampDeveloper\Config\Apache\extra\httpd- default.conf
```

and change limits:

```
    Timeout 300
    max_execution_time = 300
```

**2. php.ini:**

```
    upload_max_filesize = 256M
    post_max_size = 257M
    memory_limit = 258M
    max_input_time = 300
    max_execution_time = 300
```

After making all changes, restart your Apache server. I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Apache configuration file is httpd.conf or apache2.conf