# Script is broken after 1m, status failed, PHP-Apache when sending email with AWS SES

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-sns

Environment (shared hosting):

> Versión Apache 2.4.41
>
> Versión PHP 7.0.1
>
> Versión MySQL 10.0.38-MariaDB-cll-lve
>
> PHPMailer 6.1.4

I'm sending email messages using **AWS SNS SMTP** service through **PHPMailer**, -all configuration is well-, I made tests and worked good (1 or 2 messages), so, in production, I'm sending **100** email messages each 5 min (is not spam) but after **1m** the scrip is broken. **I don't get any error message in logs and screen**, I only can see in the console that the script is broken after 1m the body is empty. (Image below)

[image: Image blank]

**NOTES**

1. If I only send **50** email messages each time, the script is NOT broken.
2. If I run the following script:

```php
for($i = 1; $i < 131; $i++){
  echo $i.'<br>';
  sleep(1);
}
```

I get:

> **Error 500 Request Timeout This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.**

after 2m.

3. I have the following configuration in script

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 12000);
ignore_user_abort(TRUE);
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 6000);
```

4. I have the following code in `.htaccess`

```
php_value default_socket_timeout 6000
TimeOut 6000
```

I tried the changes mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498037/apache-web-server-timeout-after-60-seconds) but don't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after searching for a lot of options, I found the solution. This solution is about a special configuration for Litespeed.

Added in `.htaccess` in root directory for all request

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1]
RewriteRule .* - [E=noconntimeout:1]
```

[Run PHP without Timeouts - Litespeed Doc](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:php:run-without-timeouts)